# Expression to count values based on another calculation between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Im incredibly stuck on trying to get an expression to work on an SSRS report.
Ok to break this down I'm recreating this report from its business objects origins and this contained numerous variables.

I have 3 columns on my report that are based on these variables so the following have been created and appear to work fine.

```
=sum(Fields!No_of_cash_raised.Value)

=sum(Fields!No_of_cash_raised.Value) \ CountDistinct(Fields!TCY_REFNO.Value)

=sum(IIF((Fields!ARA_CODE.Value = "CASH" or  Fields!ARA_CODE.Value = "PYMT") AND  Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value >= DateAdd("d",-28,Parameters!P_TCY_START_DATE_TO.Value),1,0))
```

Now this is where I run into a problem with my next expression. I'm trying to do a count of ref numbers based on a calculation between 2 dates.

```
=count(Fields!TCY_REFNO.Value, IIF(Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value >= DateAdd("d",-28,Parameters!P_TCY_START_DATE_TO.Value),1,0))
```

When I try and run this report I get the "scope parameter is not valid for an aggregate function" I've looked into this error but cant find a solution. All I can say is all the fields referenced about are available in my dataset apart from the parameter field listed in my last expression. I'm using a tablix and I'm grouping on one column which isn't referenced above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283120.aspx) for the Sum function you are using the format

> Sum(expression, scope)

Where `scope` is

> (String) Optional. The name of a dataset, group, or data region that contains the report items to which to apply the aggregate function. If scope is not specified, the current scope is used.

You appear to be setting the value of this scope to be an `iif` statement that returns either a 1 or a 0, and not a dataset (such as "DataSet1").  It's not possible to use your `iif` (the aggregate function) as the scope for the sum expression.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd255237.aspx) for the Count function you are using the format

> Count(expression, scope)

Where `scope` is

> (String) The name of a dataset, group, or data region that contains the report items to which to apply the aggregate function. If scope is not specified, the current scope is used.

You *still* appear to be setting the value of this scope to be an `iif` statement that returns either a 1 or a 0, and not a dataset (such as "DataSet1").  It's not possible to use your `iif` (the aggregate function) as the scope for the count expression either.

**SOLUTION**

You need to perform a `Sum` and an `iif` to get the behavior you want.

```
=Sum(
    IIF(Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value >= 
        DateAdd("d",-28,Parameters!P_TCY_START_DATE_TO.Value)
    , 1
    , 0)
```

This way the count is only included in the Sum if `TCY_START_DATE` is greater than `P_TCY_START_DATE_TO - 28` days

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I've amended the original post as I am actually using a count and not a sum.

Comment: To also add my dataset is called "Payment_at_signup" im unclear as to the syntax for using that in my expression. Should I be removing the values of 1 and 0 as well?

Comment: Thanks. The above expression works but its not retrieving the amounts expected.  It should retrieve results similar to my other expression
** =sum(IIF((Fields!ARA_CODE.Value = "CASH" or Fields!ARA_CODE.Value = "PYMT") AND Fields!TCY_START_DATE.Value >= DateAdd("d",-28,Parameters!P_TCY_START_DATE_TO.Value),1,0))**
I will look into this some more thanks again.